# How to "merge" two JFrames together?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am desinging a GUI in Java using Swing.

I have two JFrames in my class which I would like to merge into one window, so that when the program is launched, only one window appears. However, my specific needs impose a specific layout constraint: I need to have half of my GUI displaying two components (a JTextArea component, and a JTextPane component), and the other half displaying the third one (an Image). 
I can get them to all work singly, but if I try to combine them into a "super-frame" to hold them all, it doesn't work.

I am wondering is there any other way to achieve this effect.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: show us the code you have done and sample layout/wireframe if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible to merge JFrames and you can instead use JPanels